# Vuetify v-data-table within v-data-table: content in extended-item slot malfunction

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, slot, v-data-table

in a vuetify table i do not want to show some headers and their corresponding column. Instead, I want them to be displayed in a table in the extended-item slot. The items of the table are completely user editable. This all works fine too.

The problem is that in the extended-item slot not only the properties of the selected item are displayed, but the properties of all items.

In the vue-dev-tools it is displayed correctly. I think I'm missing something fundamentally simple here. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Here is the link to the sandbox: [v-data-table in expanded-item slot of v-data-table, user editable](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-grass-9b2ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it changing `:items="tabItems"` by `:items="[item]"` (i put inside array because one item alone is not legible by :items v-data-table.

If you call tabItems you will iterate over all items again so its better to use filtered expanded-item item instead do hard work manually.

I tried in your sandbox, you can change line 54 with my suggestion and you could check that its working well.

Comment: Hi @NBlack, thank you. Seems to work. I'll test it tomorrow. Fiddling around with the Smartphone is not the fun it should be

Comment: Yes, is not the best platform to test in a Smartphone...I have tried in Google chrome and its working fine ;)

Comment: Works! Thanks for your help and stay safe;-)

Comment: Thanks ;-) same for you!